# How to create a program that checks if the number is float in javascript?

Tags: javascript, integer

In this code, I  want to check  if kcFormula is a float or not.

```
 function kToc() {
        let userInput2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('in2').value)
        let kcFormula =  userInput2 - 273.15
        res2.innerHTML = kcFormula
    }
```

If the result is float, I will make some conditions afterwards.

Comment: Guaranteed to be a float. You parse as integer and then subtract something with `.15` so it can only be `<something>.85`

Comment: Do you mean this? `const isFloat = !!(kcFormula % 1)`

Comment: trincot what is '!!'?

Comment: it's just `!` aka `not` but twice - you can use `!!` to turn any js variable into a boolean. But remember it uses truthy/falsey, which is why this would work - `!!0` turns into `false`, everything else would turn into `true`.